# Decrypting a message?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I would like to ask for a little help about the following problem, i got stuck in it and have no idea how to proceed to get the answer which Wolfram Alpha gives (of course, i am not allowed to use the solution by software).

Person A sends a message to person B s.t $a=b^{3}\in \mathbb{F}_{2038074743}$.

If $a=1933360524$, find $b$.

I know the question might be quite easy, but i don't understand the approach...

Anybody has an idea? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, if $q=2038074743$, then $q-1$ is not divisible by $3$. An option is to find a number $m$ such that $3m\equiv1\pmod{q-1}$. Because the multiplicative of $\Bbb{F}_q$ is cyclic of order $q-1$ we then get that $$a=b^3\Leftrightarrow b=a^m.$$ As $m$ is quite large, this still leaves you a "huge" modular exponentiation task. Square-and-multiply works, but I wouldn't want to attempt that with pencil & paper :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that $p:=2038074743$ is prime and $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, so $3\mid 2p-1$, hence we can define
$$b=a^{\frac{2p-1}{3}}$$
which using $(a,p)=1$ and Fermat can be shown to fulfill $b^3=a$:
$$b^3=a^{2p-1}=a^{2(p-1)+1}=(a^{p-1})^2\cdot a=a$$